# Google Trends monthly data export

Tags: export-to-csv, google-trends

If I write the following url in the browser, I get a CSV file with weekly data from Google Trends:

*`www.google.com/trends/trendsReport?q=SearchTerm&export=1`*

In the past, this file would have been the same as the one obtained by manually clicking the "export as CSV" button on the Google Trends page. But now, instead, by using this button I get a data file with monthly data.

Does anyone know whether it is possible to obtain this monthly file by using an url similar to the above-mentioned one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use date parameter with your request

```
www.google.com/trends/trendsReport?q=SearchTerm&export=1&date=01/2010 37m
```

Some pages recommend to use more than 36 months, but I tried with 140 months and always returns weekly data. Check this page for more reference, https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends

Also, you could check how to call this url

> https://www.google.com.mx/trends/api/widgetdata/multiline/csv?req=%7B%22time%22%3A%222004-01-01%202016-10-07%22%2C%22resolution%22%3A%22MONTH%22%2C%22locale%22%3A%22es-419%22%2C%22comparisonItem%22%3A%5B%7B%22geo%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22complexKeywordsRestriction%22%3A%7B%22keyword%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22BROAD%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22pope%22%7D%5D%7D%7D%5D%2C%22requestOptions%22%3A%7B%22property%22%3A%22%22%2C%22backend%22%3A%22IZG%22%2C%22category%22%3A0%7D%7D&token=APP6_UEAAAAAV_kTww_1wNWLYGrce91gQBIxkGPV4lGg&tz=300

This return a monthly data, but it appear you need to use a token

*decoded url:*

> https://www.google.com.mx/trends/api/widgetdata/multiline/csv?req={"time":"2004-01-01 2016-10-07","resolution":"MONTH","locale":"es-419","comparisonItem":[{"geo":{},"complexKeywordsRestriction":{"keyword":[{"type":"BROAD","value":"pope"}]}}],"requestOptions":{"property":"","backend":"IZG","category":0}}&token=APP6_UEAAAAAV_kTww_1wNWLYGrce91gQBIxkGPV4lGg&tz=300

Comment: where can we obtain token ... with php

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not checking this right now, but I beleve you need to do an http request, then do the login, then go to trends report and finally parse the response and read the token. I guess it's possible in some month I will return to this, if yes I'll share my results